# K-theory of stunted complex projective spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

It is well known that the inclusion
$\mathbb{R}P^{m+2}/\mathbb{R}P^{m}\hookrightarrow
\mathbb{R}P^{n}/\mathbb{R}P^{m}$ induces epimorphism in reduced
$KO$-groups.Is it true that the inclusion of stunted complex projective spaces
$\mathbb{C}P^{m+2}/\mathbb{C}P^{m}\hookrightarrow
\mathbb{C}P^{n}/\mathbb{C}P^{m}$ induces epimorphim in reduced
complex $K$-theory?

Comment: For $n\geq m$ the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow\tilde K(\mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^m)\rightarrow \tilde K\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \tilde K\mathbb{C}P^m\rightarrow 0$ implies that $\tilde K(\mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^m)\cong\mathbb{Z}^{n-m}$. Thus your map is epic if and only if $m+2\geq n\geq m$.

Comment: @Tyrone, you mean $n\geq m+2$, right? And presumably this is assumed in op as otherwise there is no inclusion.  So the answer to the op is simply yes.

Comment: The map in K-theory must be induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{C}P^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}P^{m+2}$, so we need $m+2\geq n$.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the  answer is affirmative. It follows from Th: 7.2 of the paper ' vector fields on spheres' by J.F.Adams.